# 'Error: Please install pg package manually' in js console after running npm run serve

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, vue.js, sequelize.js

After running `npm run serve` to start my Vue web app, it starts fine, but the page doesn't load and I see the following in the console.

```
Error: Please install pg package manually
_loadDialectModule connection-manager.js:81
ConnectionManager connection-manager.js:18
PostgresDialect index.js:14
Sequelize sequelize.js:322
<anonymous> main.js:32
js app.js:11203
\__webpack_require__ app.js:770
fn app.js:130
1 app.js:11265
\__webpack_require__ app.js:770
<anonymous> app.js:908
<anonymous> app.js:911
```

I've already tried installing pg and pg-hstore both locally and globally.

```
npm install --save pg pg-hstore
```

```
npm install --save -g pg pg-hstore
```

Below is part of my main.js file to test sequelize.

```
const Sequelize = require("sequelize");
const sequelize = new Sequelize(
  "postgres://USER:PASSWORD@localhost:5432/DBNAME"
);

sequelize
  .authenticate()
  .then(() => {
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
    console.log("Connection has been established successfully.");
  })
  .catch(err => {
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
    console.error("Unable to connect to the database:", err);
  });
```

Comment: https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/6907

Comment: @Adiii Thank you for your help searching. I saw that issue thread previously and was unsuccessful after trying the various fixes mentioned.

Answer (score -3):

If you have installed `sequelize` then you have to install `pg` globally.